# What is the solution to caching vs using a CSP nonce? I've been searching for a while, and haven't found it

Tags: cache, javascript, content-security-policy, http-caching

I've never seen a good answer to this dilemma, and I've been searching high and low. It seems it is a choice between using a nonce and caching, you can't have both. Really bad choice!

We're told 'unsafe-inline' is a really bad choice in CSP, and yet there seems to be no solution to the cache/nonce problem, that I've found.

Is there any solution on the horizon? Or one available now which is simply a well-kept secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This seems to be a good solution](https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-nonce-support-in-nginx/), we are using it successfully. It involves using the Nginx http_sub_module.